# CASE WHEN in SQL WHERE condition for non numerical data

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements, case-when

I have this query but I need the second `WHERE` condition to be dependent on a value in the set:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.*
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
AND TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(D,-5,GETDATE())
```

So I was going for something like this which doesn't work (because of the '>'):

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.*
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
AND CASE WHEN TABLE1.TRIGGER = 'TRUE' THEN TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(D,-5,GETDATE()) END
```

I've looked around but I was only able to find examples where the intention was to manipulate numerical info. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
AND TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(D,-5,GETDATE())
```

To:

```
AND (TABLE1.TRIGGER <> 'TRUE' or (TABLE1.TRIGGER = 'TRUE' AND TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(D,-5,GETDATE()))
```

This will either be "and true" if `TABLE1.TRIGGER` is not equal to `TRUE`, or it will perform your extra conditional check (`TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > ...`) if it *is* equal to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` results in a value, so you need to do something with it, e.g. compare it to another value:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.* 
  FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 
  WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID AND
    CASE
      WHEN TABLE1.TRIGGER = 'TRUE' THEN 1
      WHEN TABLE1.TIMESTAMP > DATEADD(D,-5,GETDATE()) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END = 1
```